# Creating image by combining two images in PHP

Tags: php, image

I want to ask a question, which unfortunately I didn't find on the Internet. I have two images and text. Can I combine all this and put some image on the background with the PHP and get JPEG output? Could I have any guide if it is possible?

Comment: ImageMagick or GD will do what you want. http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: For PHP Imagick, see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php and in particular http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php and http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php. If you provide links to your images and your text, perhaps someone can give you code. Also see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/reference.html and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/ for the basic Imagemagick commands.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick can do this for you, look for append to set them side by side.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append
   http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php

or look for composite to layer them over one another

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php